# how to suppress output when using `:=` in R {data.table}, prior to v1.8.3?

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to prevent `data.table` to print the new data.table after assigning a new column by reference? I gather standard behaviour is

```
library(data.table)
example(data.table)
DT
#    x y  v
# 1: a 1 42
# 2: a 3 42
# 3: a 6 42
# 4: b 1 11
# 5: b 3 11
# 6: b 6 11
# 7: c 1  7
# 8: c 3  8
# 9: c 6  9

DT[,z:=1:nrow(DT)]

#    x y  v z
# 1: a 1 42 1
# 2: a 3 42 2
# 3: a 6 42 3
# 4: b 1 11 4
# 5: b 3 11 5
# 6: b 6 11 6
# 7: c 1  7 7
# 8: c 3  8 8
# 9: c 6  9 9
```

i.e. the table is printed to screen after assignment. is there a way to stop data.table from showing the new table after assigning the new column z? I know I can stop this behaviour by saying

```
DT <- copy(DT[,z:=1:nrow(DT)])
```

but that is defeating the purpose of `:=` (which is designed to avoid copies).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since `<-.data.table` doesn't make a copy, you can use `<-`:

Create a data.table object:

```
library(data.table)
di <- data.table(iris)
```

Create a new column:

```
di <- di[, z:=1:nrow(di)]
di

#       Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  z
#  [1,]          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  1
#  [2,]          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  2
#  [3,]          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  3
#  [4,]          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  4
#  [5,]          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  5
#  [6,]          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  6
#  [7,]          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa  7
#  [8,]          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa  8
#  [9,]          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa  9
# [10,]          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa 10
# First 10 rows of 150 printed.
```

---

It is also worth remembering that R only prints the value of an object in interactive mode.

So, in batch mode, you can simply use:

```
di[, z:=1:nrow(di)]
```

This will not produce any output when run as a script in batch mode.

---

**Further info from Matthew Dowle:**

Also see FAQ 2.21 and 2.22 :

> *2.21 Why does `DT[i,col:=value]` return the whole of `DT`? I expected either no visible value (consistent with `<-`), or a message or return value containing how many rows were updated. It isn't obvious that the data has indeed been updated by reference.*
>
> So that compound syntax can work; e.g., `DT[i,done:=TRUE][,sum(done)]`. The number of rows updated is returned when verbosity is on, either on a per query basis or globally using `options(datatable.verbose=TRUE)`.
>
> *2.22 Ok, but can't the return value of `DT[i,col:=value]` be returned invisibly, then?*
>
> - We tried to but R internally forces visibility on for `[`. The value of
>     FunTab's eval column (see src/main/names.c) for `[` is `0` meaning force
>     `R_Visible` on (see R-Internals section 1.6). Therefore, when we tried
>     `invisible()` or setting `R_Visible` to `0` directly ourselves, `eval` in
>     src/main/eval.c would force it on again.
> - After getting used to this behaviour, you might grow to prefer it (we have). After all, how many times do we subassign using `<-` and then immediately look at the data to check it's ok?
> - We can mix `:=` into a `j` which also returns data; a mixed update and select in one query. To detect whether `j` solely updates (and then behave dierently) could be confusing.

---

**Second update from Matthew Dowle:**

We have now found a solution and v1.8.3 no longer prints the result when `:=` is used. We will update FAQ 2.21 and 2.22.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use `<-` in that case.

Comment: +10 I didn't think to try `DT<-DT[i,col:=value]`. The repetition of the variable name isn't great, but works. That gives me an idea how to get `DT[i,col:=value]` to return invisibly: now raised as [FR#2128](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2128&group_id=240&atid=978), thanks!

Comment: +1 for the mighty clever hack + interesting snippet from the FAQ.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Thank you for the edit as well as the fix in v1.8.3

Comment: Is there the potential for a hack to handle cases where the assignment takes place inside of a bracketed expression (e.g. a loop or if statement)?  It seems to still happen in 1.8.8 on R 3.0.0.

Comment: I noticed that `:=` produces output when Knit HTML is used in RStudio.  This is unexpected.  Why does knitr produce output in the resulting HTML file when none sent to the console?  Is there a way to suppress output in this case?  Is this a new question?

Comment: @MattDowle I find that data.tables some times eval invisibly and estimate that the changes introduced here are responsible. 

Example:

    f<-function () {
      d<-data.table(l=letters,n=1:26)
      d[l=='a',n:=100]
      d
    };
    
    x<-f();
    x;
    x;

the first x does not print, only the second.

Answer (score 0):

For a very long data table name, it seems that the following is equivalent in performance and can be shorter (I prefer short names but sometimes need a longer name to remember what an object really contains):

`invisible(Very.Long.Data.Table[i,col:=value])`

compare with:

`Very.Long.Data.Table<-Very.Long.Data.Table[i,col:=value]`