# How to allow output when using := in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I appreciate that the o[pposite of this question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359553/how-to-suppress-output-when-using-in-r-data-table-prior-to-v1-8-3) and incorporated as a feature in `data.table`. However, is there a way to make the output visible (preferably via `options()`)? I tried `options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)` but that returns the operations of `:=` rather than the result.

I understand I can chain `[]` at the end, but I am after a global but reversible alternative.

Comment: Are you asking on how to bring back the bug? Why should this print upon assignment? What use case do you have for this?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. The use case is: debugging. Or making sure the assignment has completed as expected.

Comment: What about `debug()` ?

Comment: I know of no such option; it shouldn't be that hard to `CTRL+F` for `[ ]` and delete it when you're done debugging.

Comment: +1: For those that use a repl-style interactive development environment (similar to Common Lisp and Slime), printing the output after assignment might be seen as a feature, not a bug.